# Вывести таблицу по значениям из двух разных таблиц

Tags: mysql

Подскажите. Необходимо вывести значения idParam только не одно а сразу несколько, 1438, 1439, 1440 и 55. то что написать в 4й строке?
Заранее благодарен.

```
select par.pRu, val.val
from Parameter par
left join VAL_2017 val on (par.Lid = val.Lid)
where idParam = 1438 
and val.Lid = 10
```

Comment: IN(1438, 1439, 1440, 55)

Comment: Так что ли?
    where idParam = IN(1438, 1439, 1440, 55)

Comment: да , именно так, только знак равно = уберите

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо. Но осталось еще одна проблема, извините я только учусь. У меня таблица создалась из 2х колонок и сначала во второй колонке у меня параметр 1438 а потом 1439. А задачка была что бы они в разных колонках (1438 и 1439) отобразились.

Comment: напишите понятней, могу предположить , что вам нужен PIVOT

Comment: Мне необходимо вывести таблицу из бд, в которой есть таблица с значением LID(idMagazin 10,20,30), ipParam(Имя товаров, 1438, 1439, 1440, 1441) и есть таблица со значениями VAL(количество товаров на складе) для параметров (Имя товаров,1438, 1439...), что бы каждый параметр (1438, 1439, 1440, 1441) отображался в отдельной колонке, и заполнена колонка значением с количеством на складе.

Comment: тогда смотрите как надо работать с PIVOT https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/